# Python - Item Price Web Scraping for Target

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get any item's price from [Target](https://www.target.com) website. I did some examples for this website using `selenium` and `Redsky API` but now I tried to wrote `bs4` code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.target.com/p/ruffles-cheddar-38-sour-cream-potato-chips-2-5oz/-/A-14930847#lnk=sametab"
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

price = soup.find("div",class_= "web-migration-tof__PriceFontSize-sc-14z8sos-14 elGGzp")
print(price)
```

But it returns me `None` .

I tried `soup.find("div",{'class': "web-migration-tof__PriceFontSize-sc-14z8sos-14 elGGzp"})`

What am I missing?

I can accept any selenium code or Redsky API code but my priority is bs4

Comment: This data is not in the source html when using a simple request with `requests`. It is rendered through js, which is why it works for Selenium (and is fetched from the api), which is why the api works aswell

Comment: You could use a combination of selenium and bs4 though if you'd like. Do you want to see that solution?

Comment: @chitown88 of course

Comment: What about finding data in xhr have you tried with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is dynamic. The data is rendered after the initial request is made. You can use selenium to load the page, and once it's rendered, then you can pull out the relevant tag. API though is always the preferred way to go if it's available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

# If you don't want to open a browser, comment out the line above and uncomment below
#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('headless')
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

url = "https://www.target.com/p/ruffles-cheddar-38-sour-cream-potato-chips-2-5oz/-/A-14930847#lnk=sametab"
driver.get(url)
r = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

price = soup.find("div",class_= "web-migration-tof__PriceFontSize-sc-14z8sos-14 elGGzp")
print(price.text)
```

**Output:**

```
$1.99
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using wrong locator.
Try this

```
price_css_locator = 'div[data-test=product-price]'
```

or in XPath style

```
price_xpath_locator = '//div[@data-test="product-price"]'
```

With bs4 it should be something like this:

```
soup.select('div[data-test="product-price"]')
```

to get the element get you just need to add `.text`

```
price = soup.select('div[data-test="product-price"]').text
print(price)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but how can I add it to my code ? can you help me ? as far as I know we can't use xpath in bs4

Comment: xpath is not allowed @Prophet

Comment: @cruisepandey I see. I just provided it for Selenium. For bs4 is the last line

Comment: @Wicaledon does the updated answer works for you?

Comment: @Prophet if I use last line, it returns me `[]`

Comment: maybe you should add some delay before `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")` to let the page loaded?

Comment: @Prophet umm, I added `time.sleep(10)` before or after this line, same thing is happening

Comment: I guess we are missing extracting the text. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Prophet now I get `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: Well, I don't really know bs4 at all :) In case it retrieves a set, you should get the first element from the set and apply `.text` on it

Answer (score 0):

use `.text`

```
price = soup.find("div",class_= "web-migration-tof__PriceFontSize-sc-14z8sos-14 elGGzp")
print(price.text)
```

Comment: thanks for answer but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @Wicaledon : Seeing just now, yes `.text` should be used on price.